# Should the logo color be used in the application theme color?

Tags: mobile-application, branding, logos

I want to ask if it is okay to have different color between logo and mobile application theme color? The logo color is too bright for application theme color, so I choose the similar color but darker. It is okay too have different color with logo color or better change the logo color so it is compatible with the application color? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "okay"? Asking whether something is "okay" is not an appropriate way to ask Questions here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a graphic design question that would be petter placed over in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to Graphic Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1):

In addition to having a few color variations for a logo (black, white, color/multicolor, etc.), it's also common practice to have a few variations of the logo itself such as standalone icon, icon + wordmark lockup, standalone wordmark, etc. It would be hard to have one logo that works for all applications.

Think about Instagram, they have both the camera icon and the cursive wordmark, both highly used and highly recognizable as Instagram. They can be used separately or together (though very seldom) depending on the platform, medium, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to have different colors for logo and theme.

What we do in our company is to have a "brand" color in our theme to use in situation where colors are pure decoration and do not compromise the experience even if they are bright. This way you maintain both a brand touch and a great experience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, totally fine. Ideally you would have a palette of colours for the company/brand. You'll need more than one colour for your application so if you don't have brand colours to work with there's no need to limit yourself to the 1 logo colour.

Answer (score 0):

This case happened to me. The brand color used by the company where I work is too bright, and it is very complicated to use on a white background.

The options you have:

- Darken the primary color of the UI (the color of the brand)
- Use a secondary if the brand has it.

It is very important when making a brand to take colors that have good accessibility (are readable).

As long as the color has enough contrast, always use the brand, this will create identity.